# Files not refreshing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I'm working with Windows Server 2008 and I have problem while changing contents of a file (say .html file). I make changes to the file, save, refresh the page and it works. But the other users are not able to see those changes until they refresh the page.

Should they not see the changes without refreshing after making changes in the server? Please advice.

Comment: Its not clear what you are specifically asking - A browser downloads a file (or opens it from disk or a network share) displays it and forgets about its origin. If it changes the browser must be told to reload it by refreshing.  This is true in general for all files, the application that has them open may implement checking to detect changes, but its application specific.

Comment: Generally if a file is changed in the server, it should have those changes when opened for the first time. But those changes are only seen when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Cached files, you will have to change their temporary Internet files settings to not store any pages. I know this can be done in IE, not sure about the other browsers.

Caching is there to make the page load from disk rather than over the Internet so it will be quicker for the end user and less onerous on the server.